# Move down row in html table Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a table where user can select multiple rows and below that there are two buttons "up" and "down". If user clicks on "down" selected rows should go down by one row and same for "up", selected rows should go up by one row, user can select any rows.

Below is my jQuery code.

For "down"

```
$(".moveDown").live("click", function(){
    var row = $("#pageDefTable .selectRow");

    row.each(function() {
        var $this=$(this);
        $this.insertAfter($this.next());
    });     

    return false;
});
```

And for "up"

```
$(".moveUp").live("click", function() {
    var row = $("#pageDefTable .selectRow");

    row.each(function() {
        var $this=$(this);
        $this.insertBefore($this.prev());
    });

    return false;
});
```

But it is not working fine. When I select upper most two rows and click on down it does not work.
And in the same way, if I select last two rows and click on up it doesn't work.

Your suggestions and help would be appreciated.

Hi Damian, the solution which you provided it works fine in normal condition. I have one more case.. I explain below, 
There are two tables say left and right > user can select any row from left table (id = metricTable ) and can move in to right table (id = pageDefTable  ) and it append at last in table and also show as a selected row in right table.

below is the code for selecting any row from left table to right table

```
        $("#center .move-row").live("click", function() {
            var tr = $("#metricTable .selectRow").remove().clone();
            $("#pageDefTable tbody").append(tr);
        return false;
        });
```

Right table is the table which has the move up and move down functionality, just after moving any row from left to right table and than I click on moveup button, it doesn't move row and when I click on second time it disappears.

Please any help and suggestions???

Comment: Show us your html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see issue with moveUp. On moveDown you need to reverse order of items:

```
$($('tr.selected').get().reverse()).each(function () {
    if ($(this).next()) {
        $(this).insertAfter($(this).next());   
    }
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7h5qy/2/)

Comment: I've updated example with stop condition not to cycle selected  elements that are already on top or bottom -> http://jsfiddle.net/7h5qy/4/

Comment: Hi Damian, the above solution which you provided it works fine in normal condition. I have one more case.. I explain below, there are two panels say left and right and both panel has table. user can select any row from left and can move in to right panel

Comment: can you provide some jsfiddle ?

Comment: I have edited my original question, included my concern there

Comment: here is jsfiddle, but I am surprised, here it is working... http://jsfiddle.net/kdhj4/1/, but same code doesn't work in the applications